# Paths for pip and python out of sync?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have an application that is using the requests module.  I have installed this module but when I try to run my app it throws the error:

```
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

When I run `pip list` i see an entry for requests:

```
...
pytz (2017.2)
requests (2.18.4)
scipy (0.19.1)
...
```

so I know it's installed.

I confirmed that both pip and python are version 2.7:

```
➜  pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
➜  python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

When I look at the paths for pip and python they look to be different:

```
➜  which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
➜  which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Am I correct in suspecting that these mismatched paths are the cause of my problem?

What would cause this to happen?  I had assumed that as long as both pip/python were 2.7 they would be working together well.

How can I fix this problem?

This seems like something that would have already been solved, but after googling and going over the suggested questions when creating this post I haven't come across a post that has a clear solution that goes over both how this could happen and how to fix it.

Comment: Please show `head -1 $(which pip)`.

Comment: @phd - that returns: `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: That's ok, your `pip` uses the same `python`, no need to "sync" them. Does your application use the same python? Next: compare `pip show requests | grep Location` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`; is the first location in the second list? What about `python -c "import requests; print('Ok')"`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying some of these options:

1) Make sure that you have an environment variable pointing to where the current pip directory is.
2) Move the pip folder to the directory that your other python packages are in.
3) Uninstall and then reinstall pip (to a different location on your path).
4) Uninstall python and then reinstall python. I would suggest installing it through conda or miniconda to make sure that you have everything downloaded to the same place. Miniconda will by default store pip with all of the other packages and should run cleanly.